# Generating shortcode and HTML on button click

Tags: plugins, plugin-gravity-forms

I should say I'm new to WordPress, so I'm not sure if this can even be done. I have a page that is made in the following way

```
[su_spoiler title="Add Call" open="yes" style="fancy" icon="arrow"]
[gravityform id=10]
[/su_spoiler]

[su_spoiler title="Add Problem" open="closed" style="fancy" icon="arrow"]
[gravityform id=7]
[/su_spoiler]

<div><button id="add-problem"> Add Problem</button></div>
```

I'm trying to get that button to append **below** the existing `Add Problem` spoiler another spoiler with the Gravity Form id 7, i.e. I'd like to generate the same code that creates the initial problem form onto my page when the button is clicked.

```
[su_spoiler title="Add Problem" open="closed" style="fancy" icon="arrow"]
[gravityform id=7]
[/su_spoiler]
```

This would mean that when every time the button is clicked, the page would be added with a spoiler and the form inside it. What are some way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would a job for Ajax. I've done a similar thing to load more posts, which is basically, onclick, load content, append content (to existing element).

I haven't finalized it entirely but I think this will give you a good nudge in the desired direction.

First we need a function which does what you want, when you click it.
Explanation is shown on [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). Make sure you also add the nopriv  if you want it to work for visitors.

```
function sd_get_more_posts() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response

    // get posts
    $post_args = array(
        // your arguments
    );
    $more_posts = get_posts($post_args);

    // echo the output, in my case I use Timber, hence why the Timber::render
    Timber::render( 'partials/overview.twig',
        array(
            'modifier' => $modifier,
            'posts'    => $more_posts
        )
    );

    // Don't forget to stop execution afterward.
    wp_die();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_more_load', 'sd_get_more_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_more_load', 'sd_get_more_posts' );
```

Using my example you need a link with the class 'load-more-posts'.
You need to add this somewhere and enqueue it.

```
jQuery(function($){

    jQuery(".load_more_posts").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // jQuery(this).addClass('hidden'); // uncomment this to hide the trigger on click.

        // you might not need them, but they show a bit of what is possible.
        offset = jQuery(this).data('offset');
        amount = jQuery(this).data('amount');

        var data = {
            'action': 'more_posts',
            'offset': offset,
            'amount': amount
        };
        jQuery.post(
            ajaxurl,
            data,
            function(response) {
                if (jQuery(response).find('.class-of-element')){
                    var newElems = jQuery(response).find('.class-of-element').html();
                    jQuery('.class-of-element').append(newElems);
                }
            }
        );
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.